# Rspec: add some header requests inside routing specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm working on a Rails application having a REST API in JSON format and versioned (according to this excellent Ryan's cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning).

For instance, there is a spec/requests spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "My Friends" do
  describe "GET /my/friends.json" do
    it "should get my_friends_path" do
      get v1_my_friends_path, {}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/vnd.myapp+json; level=1'}
      response.status.should be(401)
    end
  end
end
```

And it works well. But (keeping this example) how can we write the routing spec? For instance this spec isn't correct:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "friends routing" do
  it "routes to #index" do
    get("/my/friends.json", nil, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/vnd.myapp+json; level=1'}).
      should route_to({ action: "index",
                    controller: "api/v1/private/my/friends",
                        format: "json" })
  end
end
```

I tried different ways (such as `request.headers['Accept']` and `@request.headers['Accept']`, where `request` is undefined and `@request` is nil); I really don't see how to do.

I'm on Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6 and rspec-rails 2.11.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

By combining the ideas from Cristophe's and Piotr's answers, I came up with a solution that worked for me. I'm using rspec and rails 3.0.

```
it 'should route like i want it to' do 
  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "*/*"
  {get: "/foo/bar"}.
    should route_to(
    controller: 'foo',
    action: 'bar',
  )
  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.delete "HTTP_ACCEPT"
end
```

Comment: How did you get past the "can't modify frozen Hash" error?

Comment: @ChrisHough Hmm, I don't recall having that error. But note that this solution was for rails 3. You're likely on 4.x and they might have started freezing that DEFAULT_ENV hash since then...

Comment: Yep, I had to ditch my routing specs for request specs.  Which is totally fine by me.

Answer (score 7):

Currently you can't send addititional Headers in Routing specs, this is due to `line 608` in `actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb` where it says:

```
env = Rack::MockRequest.env_for(path, {:method => method})
```

`path` is your requested path `"/my/friends.json"` and method is `:get`
The resulting `env` contains something like the following:

```
{
 "rack.version"=>[1, 1],
 "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0xb908f5c>,
 "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0xb908fac>,
 "rack.multithread"=>true,
 "rack.multiprocess"=>true,
 "rack.run_once"=>false,
 "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
 "SERVER_NAME"=>"your-url.com", # if path was http://your-url.com/
 "SERVER_PORT"=>"80",
 "QUERY_STRING"=>"",
 "PATH_INFO"=>"/",
 "rack.url_scheme"=>"http",
 "HTTPS"=>"off",
 "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
 "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0"
}
```

If you are able to mock `Rack::MockRequest::env_for` it should be possible to inject other headers than the ones generated by env_for (see Hash above).

Other than that you are currently using the route_to matcher wrong, you should call it on a Hash where you specify the method and the path like this:

```
{ get: '/' }.should route_to(controller: 'main', action: 'index')
```

Let us know if you were able to Mock out that env_for and let it return your headers, would be nice to know.

Regards
Christoph

Comment: How did you get past the "can't modify frozen Hash" error?

Comment: I was probably using an older version of rspec or ruby, where the hash wasn't frozen.

Answer (score 5):

```
before do
  ActionDispatch::TestRequest::DEFAULT_ENV["action_dispatch.request.accepts"] = "application/vnd.application-v1+json"
end

after do
  ActionDispatch::TestRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.delete("action_dispatch.request.accepts")
end
```

Comment: How did you get past the "can't modify frozen Hash" error?

Answer (score 5):

You can using rspec's `and_wrap_original` to mock the `Rack::MockRequest.env_for` method:

```
expect(Rack::MockRequest).to receive(:env_for).and_wrap_original do |original_method, *args, &block|
  original_method.call(*args, &block).tap { |hash| hash['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/vnd.myapp+json; level=1' }
end
```

Comment: @justNeph can you expand on how you implemented this or what your spec looked like?

Comment: How did you get past the "can't modify frozen Hash" error?

Comment: @ChrisHough you can dum it and return the new hash:

Comment: @ChrisHough hash = original_method.call(*args, &block).dup

Comment: Where would I put this?  In a devise config?

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3 and 4 I had done the following in an [RSpec around hook](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/hooks/around-hooks):

```
around do |example|
  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/vnd.vendor+json; version=1'

  example.run

  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.delete 'HTTP_ACCEPT'
end
```

Since `Rack >= 2.0.3` ([used by Rails 5](https://rubygems.org/gems/actionpack/versions/5.0.0)) the `Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV` [hash is frozen](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/fd1fbab1ec8c7fc49ac805aac47b1f12d4cc5a99).

You can redefine the constant and use [Kernel.silence_warnings](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings) to silence the Ruby warnings:

```
around do |example|
  silence_warnings do
    Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV = Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.dup
  end

  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/vnd.vendor+json; version=1'

  example.run

  Rack::MockRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.delete 'HTTP_ACCEPT'
end
```

It's a bit of hack but it works like a charm.